# I want to create a trigger in mySQL

Tags: mysql

i have the following table

```
employee(id, pay-todate)
month_pay(employee_id(fk), hourly_pay_rate, hours_worked)
```

How would i go about creating a trigger that inserts
the total of(hourly_pay_rate x hours_worked) into pay-todate
whenever a new row is added to month_pay?

I also need to subtract 10% if the pay-todate is 10 000 or greater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER insert_pay_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON month_pay
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   insert into employee (id, `pay-todate`)
   select NEW.employee_id, 
          case when NEW.hourly_pay_rate * NEW.hours_worked >= 100000
               then NEW.hourly_pay_rate * NEW.hours_worked * 0.9
               else NEW.hourly_pay_rate * NEW.hours_worked
          end;
END
|
delimiter ;
```